# Unicode is not shown in meta tag

Tags: html, unicode, meta-tags

I have used unicode in my website's meta tag as follows.

`<meta property="og:title" content="ශ්‍රී ලංකා" />`

But when I get view source in browser, it is shown as follows.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="????????" />
```

How can I avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: More info needed, like a URL, or description of HTTP headers and the way the file has been saved (is it really UTF-8). It could be a font issue in the source viewer, too. (Which browser, which viewer?)

Comment: Here is the link. http://www.phonekade.com and I tried with both firefox and chrome. Of course, the file is in UTF-8. The problem is only with meta tags. See this page. http://www.phonekade.com/Paid-Ads-pid4.html. In it Unicode is shown smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

With an editor like [Notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), you must change the file encoding to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

[image: Encoding]

Answer (score 2):

The Sinhala characters in your file have been converted to question marks somewhere in the process of uploading to the server or in server actions. They are actual question marks “?”, U+003F, not problem indicators used by browsers or source viewers. Question marks also appear near the very end of the page in visible content, line 445: `<a href="http://www.bitak.net" title="?????" target="_blank">?????</a>`

The page appears to be served simply from a static HTML file by an Apache server, with no special server-side technology (though one cannot be sure, when looking from outside). This suggests that something has gone wrong in the upload process, like incorrect character code conversion (assuming you have checked that the file in your authoring system is UTF-8 encoded and displays correctly). This may happen if you transfer a file in “text mode” or “Ascii mode”, so I suggest uploading it again, in as raw mode as possible.

Comment: Thanks for showing line 445. I didn't see it. Can you please see this link? http://www.phonekade.com/Paid-Ads-pid4.html. In it Unicode is shown properly? How is that possible if there is a problem in upload process? I'm using filezilla and it has 3 options for transfer type as Auto, ASCII and Binary. I used ASCII. Is it wrong? (what do you mean by raw mode?) Thank you.

Comment: You can't transfer Unicode text data in ASCII mode. Use Binary mode instead.

Comment: @Bhathiya, by raw I meant binary. This other page looks mostly OK, with Sinhala characters in content, but it, too, has question marks in `meta` tags and in the link near the end. I could understand this is e.g. server-side includes are used, so that the start and the end of the document come from separate files, which have been transferred in a wrong mode.